# Display text from local text file into a div? (No webserver)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am a Twitch streamer and I am currently trying to animate any text on my stream the way I want it animated. I use a thing called stream labels, which gets the latest information from my stream, and outputs it to a folder on my pc as a .txt file.

What I am trying to do is to call upon the .txt file in a div, style it, and use the file by using OBS browsersource. I have it animated and it does display the text, but cant figure out a way to style it (the content within the object). I am terrible with JS, and I have read that you cannot call upon local files with JS. Is there anything that I could use to make this happen?

This is what I have:

```
 <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>


<div id="element-animation">
</div>


<script>
document.getElementById('element-animation').innerHTML += '<object type="text/html" data="most_recent_follower.txt"></object>';
</script>

<script>
</script>


</body>
```

The problem is, using this way would be no different then just using the object tag in the html, and the object content cannot be styled.

Comment: iframe........?

Comment: cannot style iframe content either.

Comment: the fetch it using ajax...

Comment: again....terrible with this stuff. Pretty much know html and css. Link or example? Ill try to google it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to learn the basic of javascript... Specially about AJAX.

To get everything from a file into your document you need to use ajax - to use ajax you probably need a server unless some security flags is turned off.

```
jQuery(function($){
  $.get("most_recent_follower.txt", function(txt) {
    $('#element-animation').text(txt)
  })
})
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. I agree I still need to learn a lot, but there is nothing wrong with asking for help and learning from others as well. Again, thanks for the help. Cheers!