# How to insert the data from a .txt file into a html

Tags: javascript, html, src

I would like to insert the data from a text file into a html. How can I do that? Is there something wrong in my code. That only thing I know is the path of the text file. Thanks.

```
document.getElementById("description").src =  "/bestreads/books/alannathefirstadventure/description.txt";
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Display text from local text file into a div? (No webserver)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40269137/display-text-from-local-text-file-into-a-div-no-webserver)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **JavaScript** and the `XMLHttpRequest` object.

Something like this:

**Declare your XHR function:**

```
function sendXHR(type, url, data, callback) {
  var newXHR = new XMLHttpRequest() || new window.ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  newXHR.open(type, url, true);
  newXHR.send(data);
  newXHR.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.status === 200 && this.readyState === 4) {
      callback(this.response);
    }
  };
}
```

**Then you can use:**

```
sendXHR("GET", "/bestreads/books/alannathefirstadventure/description.txt", null, function(response) { // response contains the content of the description.txt file.
  document.getElementById("description").innerHTML = response; // Use innerHTML to get or set the html content.
});
```

Please, you can find more information about `XMLHttpRequest` object, [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest).

About `innerHTML`, [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML).

Answer (score 1):

You need to "read" the file first, if you are using Jquery, you can do:

```
$.get("bestreads/books/alannathefirstadventure/description.txt", function(data) {
     document.getElementById("description").src=data;
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! But how do I declare '$'??

Comment: Sorry. I need to do that without jquery, because the html file is provided, and it does not install jquery library.

Answer (score 1):

Your current code will just print **bestreads/books/alannathefirstadventure/description.txt** .To print the content from the text file to your html div, you will need to read the file, get its data in a variable and assign that variable to your div's src like below code:

```
$.get("bestreads/books/alannathefirstadventure/description.txt", function(data) {
     document.getElementById("description").src=data;
});
```

In above code, `data` will have entire content from the specified text file.
Please verify location of text file as its a common mistake programmers make.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! How do I declare '$'??

Comment: Sorry. I need to do that without jquery, because the html file is provided, and it does not install jquery library.

Answer (score 1):

It might be worth mentioning a pure html way of doing this with [object tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/object)

you should be able to do

```
<div><object data="/bestreads/books/alannathefirstadventure/description.txt"></object></div>
```

However, css won't apply to the text.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, but I would like to do that on Javascript...